# Limiting form submission rate by IP address and time interval

Tags: php, mysql, forms, ip, intervals

On a previous question about how I could limit the amount of times a form is submitted in an hour, someone said this:

```
select count(*) from mysql_table where uid='$uid' and timestamp > (DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR););
```

That seem's like it would work, but I have no idea how. First I'd like to replace uid with IP:

```
select count(*) from mysql_table where ip='$ip' and timestamp > (DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR););
```

But after that I'm not quite sure how the timestamp > (DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL - 1 HOUR);); actually works. I do submit a timestamp with each post, but I don't know how the rest actually works, can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query counts how many records are present in "mysql_table"

```
select count(*) from mysql_table
```

and limit that count to records having ip=user_ip

```
where ip='$ip'
```

and timestamp (the date/time column in which recording time is stored) is greater than time representing "one hour ago"

```
timestamp > (DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR)
```

(remember that every time you insert a record, you probably set timestamp field to current date/time).
What you have to do is comparing this result with maximum allowed and decide if it's good or not.